# Can I search subtitle in tableview?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have 2 labels: **Title** and **Subtitle** on each tableview cell. Now I can search for the title. And I want to search subtitle with search bar,

How can I do it?

Here is how my app looks like:

[image]

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
    filteredObjects = objects.filter { object in

  return object.title.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString) || object.subtitle.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString)

    }

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

This function searches through the subtitles!

Happy coding!

Comment: Let me know if you need any other help! Also, please tap the checkmark to accept the answer, so if anyone else has the problem in the future, they can see the answer worked!